# .NET Filtering compare countries xml to countries in database

Tags: c#, .net, ajax

I have a .net app that is using a countries.xml to populate a dropdown of countries called from ajaxToolkit webservice method. The box populates the all countries and is required for subsequently populating the regions then cities.

I would only like to show countries that are in the users table in the mssql database. Is there a way to do this without re-writing all the code? Like filtering the results using a compare or something?

Larry

Comment: Assuming that your collections are held in something that inherits from `IEnumerable<T>` - `return A.Where(a => B.Any(b => a.identifyingFeature == b.identifyingFeature));`

Answer (score 0):

I would personally modify the web service method to do something like:

```
Read the distinct list of countries from the users table into an indexable list (i.e. Dictionary).

For each country in the countries file
  if there is an entry in the list of user countries
    add the country to a list of countries to return from the web service method

Return the filtered list of countries
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static List<Countries> countries = new List<Countries>();

List<Countries> results = countries.FindAll(findCountriesThatAreInDatabase); 

/* the input argument findCountriesThatAreInDatabase is a 
  delegate that checks for the countries that exists in your database. */
```

Ideally it could be,

```
private static bool findCountriesThatAreInDatabase(Countries c)
        {
  //Here you have to check whether the country you are trying 
  //add to the list exists in your database.

       }
```

For more reference you could refer to FindAll() in msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z.aspx

This is the generic answer that I could think of based on your question.